# Consequences of a Parent Child Relationship in akka

Tags: scala, akka, actor

```
import akka.actor._
case object ChildMessage

implicit val as = ActorSystem()

class Child extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case ChildMessage => println("I'm a child")
  }
}

class ParentWithExplicitChildren extends Actor {
  val children = Array.fill(5)(context.actorOf(Props[Child]))
  def receive = {
    case ChildMessage => children.foreach(_ ! ChildMessage)
    case _ => println("I'm a parent")
  }
}

class ParentWithActorRefs extends Actor {
  val shamChildren = Array.fill(5)(as.actorOf(Props[Child]))
  def receive = {
    case ChildMessage => shamChildren.foreach(_ ! ChildMessage)
    case _ => println("I'm a parent")
  }
}

val parent = as.actorOf(Props[ParentWithExplicitChildren])
parent ! ChildMessage
// Will shut down children
parent ! PoisonPill


val shamParent = as.actorOf(Props[ParentWithActorRefs])
shamParent ! ChildMessage
// WONT shut down children
shamParent ! PoisonPill
```

Using the example above I can only think of two consequences of not having an explicit Parent Child relationship.

1. Poison Pill won't explicitly kill the actor refs contained in ParentWithActorRefs
2. ParentWithActorRefs's context.children will be empty

Are they other consequences?  Does the non-child message relaying potentially have different message ordering semantics than the child message relaying?  Can I not access ParentWithExplictChildren's child actor refs with actorSelection?

Comment: Just as a note, in `ParentWithExplicitChildren`, you do not need `val children` there as the children will always be accessible via `context.children`.  You don't need an explicit `val` to hold those refs.

Comment: also, there's no need to close over "as" to create the top-level "children", just use "context.system".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two consequences are correct.  You missed one though in the fact that when `ParentWithExplicitChildren` fails itself, it will stop and then start again all of it's children because it's the explicit supervisor for those children.  In the case of `ParentWithActorRefs`, a failure in this actor will not stop the `shamChildren` because it's not their supervisor; the root guardian is.

Also, yes, you can access the children of `ParentWithExplicitChildren` refs via actor selection.  They are proper actors with addressable paths and thus can be looked up and communicated with from outside of their parent/supervising actor.